# i have problems with uv unwraping and scaling in it

Tags: uv

so iam trying to uv unwrap my model but in order to get them in perfect shape for the rendering i had to scale them outside the uv grid like in the picture.i know its not good but i dont know how to solve this problem myself iam still new to blender so i dont really know a lot about texturing and nothing about baking so i use pbr's from texture.com and poligon.com and others.i didnt do seams manually i used (F3) searched for ( smart uv) island margin =0.03.so is there a way to put the uvs i did in the uv grid without destroying the texture i want[image]

this is the picture if the square is inside the uv grid which is I don't want
[image]

anyone has any good idea about this

Answer (score 0):

Set your model inside the bounds of the UV grid. Do the scaling with texture coordinates and mapping nodes in the material editor.

But if you're not running a heavily optimized scene you can leave it outside the bounds of the UV.

Comment: ohhhh thank you man never thought of that before for some reason. thank you